# How to wait till the job status api reaches to status = success in python based pytest test automation framework

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

I have a problem statement as below -
I have a job status api which accepts `job_id` and start checking the status of the job.

The job statuses are as follows:

1. In Queue.
2. In Progress.
3. Going to next queue.
4. Success in queue 2.
5. Job is completed successfully.

Now how should I wait until the api response returns `status = "Job is completed successfully"` as well as printing the previous status.

I do not want to hardcode or use `time.sleep(900)`. I want to check periodically and print the status accordingly.

So far i have this code:

```py
logger.info('---Getting Job Latest Status')
headers = {
    "authorization": access_token
}
latest_job_status_url = f"localhost" + job_id + "/latest_status"
latest_task_url = f"{latest_job_status_url}"
latest_status_job_result = exec_request("GET", latest_task_url, headers,"null")
```

```py
def exec_request():
    api_response = requests.Session().request(
        method=request_type,
        url=api_url,
        headers=headers,
        params=payload,
        verify=False
    )
    api_content = api_response.content
    api_response_content = json.loads(api_content.decode('utf-8'))
    return {
        'content': api_response_content,
        'status_code': api_response.status_code
    }
```

How can I make this function periodically print the status?

Adding the Code from comment :
@Luke

````
def wait_for_job_to_complete_and_return_status(job_id):
    job_api_response_result = get_job_latest_status(job_id)
    job_internal_status = job_api_response_result.get('internal_status')
    while (job_internal_status != "SUCCESS" or job_internal_status != "FAIL"):
        time.sleep(50)
        job_internal_status = get_job_latest_status(job_id)
        logger.info("---Internal Status is : %s", job_internal_status .get('internal_status'))
    return job_internal_status
    ```
````

Comment: How do you define "periodically"? `Time.sleep` waits a period before doing the next action (in this case checking again), are you sure you definitely do not want to use this?

Comment: Yes i do not want to hard code the time here. It might take 10 mins to complete the job sometimes 15 mins. If the job completes in 10 mins and if i hard code the time as 15 mins then the function needs to wait for extra 5 more minutes before doing next action.

Comment: Can't you just check like every 30 seconds or something?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly it's not `Time.sleep` you have a problem with, it's more making sure that you wait until the job is done? If so we can use a technique called [Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science))

Here's some example code

```
def get_status(job_id):
  logger.info('---Getting Job Latest Status')
  headers = {
    "authorization": access_token
  }
  latest_job_status_url = f"localhost" + job_id + "/latest_status"
  latest_task_url = f"{latest_job_status_url}"
  latest_status_job_result = exec_request("GET", latest_task_url, headers,"null")
  return latest_status_job_result

def wait_for_completion(job_id):
  status = get_status(job_id)

  while status != "Job is completed successfully":
    print("Job is not completed. Current status", status)
    Time.sleep(5) #wait 5s
    status = get_status(job_id)
```

Basically, we ask the job for its status to get started - no point asking for updates if it is already finished!

Then, we sleep for 5 seconds and ask again. If after 5 seconds it still isn't complete, we sleep for another 5 seconds and ask again. If after that 5 seconds it still isn't complete, we sleep for another 5 seconds and ask again, and so on until the job is complete.

By using this loop we could be waiting 0s (if it completes immediately), 20s, 40s, 5 minutes, basically however long it takes for the job to complete

---

## Edit:

Looking at your updated code, it looks like the outcome is not just in the `job_internal_status` variable - your logger is calling `.get` here, so we probably want that in our loop exit check too. If you don't need anything else from this variable (you literally just need to return `SUCCESS` or `FAIL`) then the following should work:

```
def wait_for_job_to_complete_and_return_status(job_id):
    job_api_response_result = get_job_latest_status(job_id)
    job_internal_status = job_api_response_result.get('internal_status')
    while (job_internal_status != "SUCCESS" or job_internal_status != "FAIL"):
        time.sleep(50)
        job_internal_status = get_job_latest_status(job_id).get('internal_status')
        logger.info("---Internal Status is : %s", job_internal_status)
    return job_internal_status
```

Otherwise, we can try something like the following:

```
def wait_for_job_to_complete_and_return_status(job_id):
    job_api_response_result = get_job_latest_status(job_id)
    job_internal_status = job_api_response_result.get('internal_status')
    while (job_internal_status != "SUCCESS" or job_internal_status != "FAIL"):
        time.sleep(50)
        job_api_response_result = get_job_latest_status(job_id)
        job_internal_status = job_api_response_result.get('internal_status')
        logger.info("---Internal Status is : %s", job_internal_status)
    return job_internal_status
```

Comment: I tried something like this : 
def wait_for_job_to_complete_and_return_status(job_id):
    job_api_response_result = get_job_latest_status(job_id)
    job_internal_status = job_api_response_result.get('internal_status')
    while (job_internal_status != "SUCCESS" or job_internal_status != "FAIL"):
        time.sleep(50)
        job_api_status = get_job_latest_status(job_id)
        logger.info(job_api_status.get('internal_status'))
        logger.info(job_api_status.get('eta_value'))    
    return job_internal_status

This is not out of loop even after api returns fail or success

Comment: @Ashu123 it's difficult to read that code in a comment (may be easier to read if you edit it into your question). However, it looks like your loop is checking the value of `job_internal_status` but the calling code is only updating `job_api_status`, so you are trapped in an infinite loop as you are not updating the value that is being checked

Comment: Added the code in the Question